# Transfer-Encoding: identity results in 400 Bad Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, apache2.4

I am having issues with a put request that sends a header `Transfer-Encoding: identity` to my API service.

The request is a multipart/form-data request, which results in a 400 BAD REQUEST, with this error message:

```
[Thu Jan 26 16:46:30.364801 2017] [core:info] [pid 14433:tid 139751667468032] [client IP] AH02539: client sent unknown Transfer-Encoding (identity): URL_here
```

While testing, If I change the header to `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` all works fine.

Problem is that request is coming from a service I can not change. Any ideas why this issue?